# Hard-on-Average, Quasi-Polynomial-Time Problems

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, average-case-complexity

In a [paper by Raphael Pass](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-39200-9_10), he writes (page 162):

> ... most natural problems that we believe are hard on average for **polynomial**
> time are also believed hard for **quasi-polynomial** time.

In [another post by Turkistany](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3620/873), he mentioned that the **log-CLIQUE** problem is solvable in quasi-polynomial time.

What are some other **natural** problems which we believe are *hard on average* for polynomial time, but can be decided/solved in quasi-polynomial time?