# On proving the standard $p$-measure on $NP$ assumption?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np, nondeterminism, barriers, complexity-assumptions

In the answer here [An Anthology of Complexity Assumptions](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5961/an-anthology-of-complexity-assumptions/6119#6119) an interesting assumption is made. The assumption is $p$-measure of $NP$ is not $0$. There are many non-trivial consequences that follow from it that do not follow from a **single** standard assumption in complexity theory practiced.

1. I am wondering what has been considered to prove this assumption?
2. Is there any attempt and do the standard barriers to prove $P\neq NP$ apply here?
3. Could a single non-deterministic algorithm of some sort prove such an assumption?